# How do you use an input in PyScript?

Tags: google-chrome, input, pyscript

The basic python inputs code doesn't work right when I open them on google chrome. is there a different was to write the code in `PyScript`, that's still as simple as the normal inputs? I really don't want to have to convert everything to JavaScript, mostly because I would need to learn how JavaScript works. (also sorry about the formatting I literally just use notepad)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<body>

<py-script>

print("welcome to madlibs!")
print('please do not put any spaces in your answers')
print("")
print("")
print("")
name1 = input('name?')
```

[this is what happens when I open it on google chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EHi3.png) it doesn't even let the page load until it has input.

I wanted it to run how it would in python, but upon further google searches I learned that will never happen. I thought at least it would put the question in the input box, but it didn't do that either.

Answer (score 1):

You need a browser-aware program.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  welcome to madlibs!<br>
  please do not put any spaces in your answers'<br><br><br><br>
  <button id="button">Input</button>
  name = <span id="span"></span>
  <py-script>
    import js
    from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy

    def input_name(event):
      name = input()
      js.document.getElementById("span").innerText = name

    proxy = create_proxy(input_name)
    js.document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", proxy)
  </py-script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple use cases you could `prompt()` the user for `input()`...

```py
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
    from pyscript import window
    input = window.prompt

name1 = input('name?')
```