# Problem running these simple codes in Pyscript

Tags: python, pyscript

i am still a newbie in learning Python, i try to insert my simple codes into pyscript but cannot work. Does anyone knows what is the problem? Many thanks in advance for helping me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <py-script>
            print("Welcome to the Shen Ho's Lunch Expenses Calculator!")
            bill = float(input("What was the total bill? RM "))
            tax = int(input("How much percent of service tax in the bill? "))
            people = int(input("How many people to split the bill? "))


            total_tax_amount = (bill * tax) / 100
            total_bill = bill + total_tax_amount
            bill_per_person = total_bill / people
            final_amount = round(bill_per_person, 2)

            print(f"Each person should pay: RM{final_amount}")
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below are the errors i received:

1. Once opened the html file, this screen popup with a empty box:
   [image]
2. Inside the empty box, if i click "cancel", then this error popup:
   [image]
3. Inside the empty box, if i click "ok", then this error popup:
   [image]

Hope you guys can help me, i am just a beginner of python programming, thanks alot!!!

Comment: can you show what error you are getting? it works good for me.

Comment: I am not sure you can use `print()` and `input()` effectively in that way in py-script. I don't think you are going to see any of the `print()` or prompts until after stuff is processed. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001015/how-do-you-use-an-input-in-pyscript

Comment: @Abhi747  thanks for the help. I have uploaded the error screenshots in my post.

Comment: @JonSG  i see... how come pyscript so complicated? I thought was easy only coz just put all codes inside the html. I am still a beginner of Python, all i want is just able to deploy my program and share it with my friend and for them to play with my program.

Comment: @Shen Those pop-ups you're getting that say "This page says..." are the page handling your input prompts. If you enter a float at the first one, and ints at the next two it will complete the program.  
  Pyscript isn't really designed to just take a python script you would normally run in a terminal and just run it in a browser as is.  It does allow information to be passed between JS and Python, can manipulate the HTML and gives access to some APIs that JavaScript doesn't have (like local file manipulation).

Comment: If you just need `input()` and `print()` and some very basic Python, you can avoid the use of Pyscript and use things in the Jupyter ecosystem. Pyscript is still very much in development and you seem to have limited knowledge of the HTML and Javascript needed to work successfully with it. I'm basing that on your own statement, " how come pyscript so complicated? I thought was easy only coz just put all codes inside the html." Apologies if I'm wrong. Using Jupyter and serving temporary sessions via MyBinder would be as easy "put all codes inside " a notebook on GitHub and share a link.