# how do i make a interactive Pyscript terminal with input and output?

Tags: pyscript

I want to host a python script on a website with pyscript, which has both console input and console output. how exactly do i do that?

i used https://pyscript.com/ to make the website and github pages to deploy it. i couldn't see the preview on pyscript.com.

this is most of the python code. the only things that i left out here are the encrypt and decrypt keys:

```
def encrypt(message):
    encrypted_message = ""
    for letter in message:
        if letter in encrypt_key:
            encrypted_message += encrypt_key[letter]
        else:
            encrypted_message += letter
    return encrypted_message

def decrypt(encrypted_message):
    decrypted_message = ""
    for letter in encrypted_message:
        if letter in decrypt_key:
            decrypted_message += decrypt_key[letter]
        else:
            decrypted_message += letter
    return decrypted_message

while True:
    message = input('message to crypt: ')
    task = input('encrypt or decrypt? ')
    if task == 'encrypt':
        encrypted_message = encrypt(message)
        print(encrypted_message)
    
    elif task == 'decrypt':
        decrypted_message = decrypt(message)
        print(decrypted_message)
    else:
        break
```

on the website, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python311.zip/\_pyodide/\_base.py", line 499, in eval_code
.run(globals, locals)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/lib/python311.zip/\_pyodide/\_base.py", line 340, in run
coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "\<exec\>", line 68, in \<module\>
File "\<exec\>", line 32, in input
Exception: input() doesn't work when PyScript runs in the main thread.
Consider using the worker attribute: https://pyscript.github.io/docs/2023.11.2/user-guide/workers/
```

Comment: There's a lot on using `input()` in conjunction with pyscript in StackOverflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001015/how-do-you-use-an-input-in-pyscript/76001542#76001542) and others that should come up with a search, & so it is hard to follow what you missed about the exception ' input() doesn't work when PyScript runs in the main thread'? There's even a direct link to https://pyscript.github.io/docs/2023.11.2/user-guide/workers/ that further discusses how you don't want to block things in your main thread. There's also this reddit post asking much the same as you ...

Comment: <comment> [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PyScript/comments/xcg27f/how_to_simulate_a_console_in_pyscript/) that discusses some of the challenges you are facing. And as that latter post references, there is already a console option for pyodide, which underlies the kernel involved for pyscript. You can use Pyodide in conjunction with JupyterLite to do something like you describe separate from pyscript. Example of a working version is [here as part of the sympy documentation site](https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html).  ....

Comment: <continued>  (A simpler version separated from the sympy documentation site is [here](https://live.sympy.org/).) The console allows you to try sympy examples right there using pyodide as the Python-enabling kernel. More on how they did it is covered [here](https://github.com/sympy/live) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sympy/c/mX2Ckn7ru3A/m/utrLb-NnAAAJ) and at links therein.

Comment: It sounds like you need to add the `worker` attribute to your `<script type="py">` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
    from pyscript import window
    input = window.prompt

message = input('message to crypt: ')
```